# How to consume messages within specific timestamps using reactor kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor-kafka

I need to consume messages from a Kafka topic within a specific time range. It is easy enough to determine the starting offset with the help of `partition.seekToTimestamp(startTimeInMillis)` like the code below:

```
ReceiverOptions<ByteBuffer, ByteBuffer> options =
        receiverOptions
            .subscription(topicConfig.getTopics())
            .pollTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(topicConfig.getPollWaitTimeoutMs()))
            .addAssignListener(
                partitions -> {
                  partitions.forEach(partition -> partition.seekToTimestamp(startTimeInMillis));
                });
```

but how do I stop consuming once the messages start exceeding the end timestamp?
I can use the below code:

```
KafkaReceiver.create(options)
        .receive()
        .takeWhile(record -> record.timestamp() < endTimeInMillis)
        .map(this::handleConsumerRecord);
```

But the problem is that when the condition is met for a message, that message might be the last valid mesage in its partition, but it might be possible that other partitions in the topic still have messages below the end timestamp.

How do I ensure that I have consumed all the messages across partitions within the end timestamp?

Comment: What if you had multiple instances of your application in your consumer group, all consuming different partitions? Basically, you need an external database to track when you've reached that timestamp for all consumers

Comment: Nope, I will have just the one instance and due to various design constraints, consuming from Kafka is the only solution I have.

Comment: Okay, maybe "now" you have one instance, but "in production", you should ideally scale out your consumers. Regardless, you need an external store to track when threads read those offsets